# cargo build-bpf rustc version

Tags: solana-program, rust, rustc

I'm trying to use "cargo build-bpf" on a simple rust file, I'm using the "solana_program" dependency and the next error occurs:
"error: package `solana-program v1.16.5` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev"
When I'm running "rustc -V", the result is "rustc 1.71.0 (8ede3aae2 2023-07-12)", I've tried to reinstall cargo and rustc and it didn't help. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an older version of the Solana CLI / build tools. The build tools that come bundled with Solana 1.14 use Rust 1.62, but version 1.16 of the Solana CLI uses Rust 1.68.

If you want to resolve the issue and build `solana-program` version `1.16` in your program, you simply need to update your Solana CLI. This command updates to the current latest as of this writing:

```
$ solana-install init 1.16.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, I've tried fixing it all day long

Answer (score 1):

Are you using WSL? there are binding issues between the rust compiler & compiler solana uses when compiling through CLI.

You can lock back to a compatible version by adding this to cargo:
`solana-program = "=1.14.17"`

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, I've tried this and now the error is "failed to select a version for the requirement `once_cell = "^1.12.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 1.17.2, 1.17.1, 1.17.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `solana-frozen-abi v1.14.17`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-frozen-abi = "=1.14.17"` (locked to 1.14.17) of package `solana-program v1.14.17"

Comment: ^I've added solana-program = "=1.14.17" to the Cargo.toml file, and then got this error

Comment: Can you just provide your full Cargo file so we can see what other deps you need?

Comment: Cargo file: "[package]
name = "tt"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "tt"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
constant_time_eq = "0.3.0"
solana-program = "1.14.17"