# problem with running tests for every program in local env

Tags: solana-program, anchor-test, program-test

**Problem with local env. tests fail**

**Account doesn't get initiated every time for other program tests as well, but works on solpg**

**anchor test**
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.10s

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

**Running test suite: "/home/madhan/dev/solana/program-examples/tokens/spl-token-minter/anchor/Anchor.toml"**

yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ /home/madhan/dev/solana/program-examples/tokens/spl-token-minter/anchor/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'

SPL Token Minter
1) Create an SPL Token!
2) Mint some tokens to your wallet!

0 passing (117ms)
2 failing

1. SPL Token Minter
   Create an SPL Token!:
   **Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete**
   at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5922:13)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
   at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5881:20)
   at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:284:21)
   at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:144:14)
   at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
2. SPL Token Minter
   Mint some tokens to your wallet!:
   **Error: AnchorError caused by account: mint_account. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012.** Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.
   at Function.parse (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:167:14)
   at translateError (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/error.ts:276:35)
   at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

**- Edit**

**tx logs from .anchor after adding {skipPreflight: true} inside of the .rpc() method**

Streaming transaction logs mentioning AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx. Confirmed commitment

Transaction executed in slot 6:
Signature: 3oxzqTbUWnqbKEyoMgZ4XGx6dUr2e2BKmpdW32FE6SLqht65xHR6smv5SfZbTN63u37kCvcyYubmGgGjxCRZ7g6w

Status: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Log Messages:
Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx invoke [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39jaa.png)

```
Program log: Instruction: CreateToken

Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx consumed 8173 of 200000 compute units

Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx failed: Invoked an instruction with data that is too large (12884933564 > 10240)
```

Transaction executed in slot 7:
Signature: 5BFo6C3n1Mp5gmu9QsAZJ5SgrFSBdEm3hrmdbQBdoFuEhR7wimXiAYqywWyVzozNVbhAykUQvcMjhwnZMnXqSEdZ

Status: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbc4

Log Messages:
Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx invoke [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39jaa.png)
Program log: Instruction: MintTo

Program log: AnchorError caused by account: mint_account. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012.

Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.

Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx consumed 5093 of 200000 compute units

Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx failed: custom program error: 0xbc4

**- Edit 2**

[image: Versions and errors]

[image: Dependencies]

New dependency error shows up everytime during build with the errors mentioned in the img

Comment: using latest versions of all currently.

Comment: can you add the transaction logs from .anchor or add {skipPreflight: true} inside of the .rpc() method for better logs? I assume this is a version issue but want to be sure.

Comment: @Sav - Edited the question to add the logs from .anchor after adding skipPreflight to true.

Comment: I had this problem not too long ago, and the solution below from Jonas will work. You may have to tweak versions of anchor (if using 0.28, try 0.27 or 0.26), and pin certain dependencies like winnow & toml_datetime

Comment: @Sav - I face problems with the build. used the CLI version, Jonas suggested, stable one as well but one or the other dependencies say can't build with the rustc version, even though I have the stable rustc version. tried pinning dependencies and changing anchor versions as well, but didn't work.

Comment: Post the error message, your CLI & Anchor versions, and your Cargo.toml dependencies here if possible

Comment: edited them in question under Edit 2 

Comment: Went ahead and attempted to replicate your config, and was able to get a successful build with the following:
Solana CLI v1.14.20
Anchor CLI v0.27.0
Cargo.toml ---
anchor-lang/anchor-spl = version 0.26.0
winnow="=0.4.1"
toml-datetime="=0.6.1"
solana-program="=1.14.18"
Remove toml-edit, and keep mpl-token-metadata the same. Give this a try and let me know. If it doesn't work, feel free to reach out to me on Discord @0xsavant and I'd be happy to help further. Just don't want to drag out the comment chain

Answer (score 4):

Program AQDdxLFXQk6eBsVEW1HiHKKH77QMzSK2vMCbjMPhERHx failed: Invoked an instruction with data that is too large (12884933564 > 10240)

This means you are compiling with the wrong cli version. Try 1.14.20 instead:
[Program failed to complete: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933924 > 1280)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/program-failed-to-complete-instruction-passed-to-inner-instruction-is-too-large)

Comment: Build fails when using 1.14.20. tried fixing in few dependencies, but kept getting
" package `constant_time_eq v0.3.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.66.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev " like this

Comment: [https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/cargo-build-bpf-rustc-version](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/cargo-build-bpf-rustc-version)

checked with this, but tests fail like before again

Comment: This maybe solved in anchor 0.28.0 in combination with 1.16.5 is it an option to upgrade for you?

Comment: tried running it after upgrading it, but this time anchor-spl is creating issues. 
[The issue](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6991/how-to-fix-error-the-trait-borshserialize-is-not-implemented-for-pubkey)

Comment: Maybe have a look at this :https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7196/how-to-fix-borsh-serialize-error-on-anchor-0-28-when-publishing-crates

Comment: ser, this solution uses old solana-program,still not working